# Comic where time-travel assassination of Hitler backfires

Tags: story-identification, comics, time-travel

*(Asking on behalf of an [anonymous person on the internet whose mention of the comic](http://bbs.boingboing.net/t/tom-the-dancing-bug-percival-dunwoody-idiot-time-traveler-from-1909/25456/13) piqued my interest -- so unfortunately, I cannot offer any more details.)*

> [...] A comic where someone goes back to kill Hitler and it results in an actual 1000-year Reich, because although he successfully killed Hitler, the Nazis got hold of the laser rifle the assassin had brought back with him to do the job. So, another dude gets sent to kill that dude, but that doesn't work out either, so another dude gets sent, then another, then another....
>
> I must have read it in the early 1980s or so, but it could easily have been a story from earlier [...]

Comment: Sounds interesting.

Comment: Very diffifult to determine from your description. The trope (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HitlersTimeTravelExemptionAct?from=Main.ptitlekz83hawz) is very extensive

Comment: http://www.viruscomix.com/page382.html

Comment: http://www.tor.com/stories/2011/08/wikihistory

Comment: To find a work of fiction where time-travel assassination of Hitler does **not** backfire would be a much harder job.

Comment: @vsz - for *kidnapping*, on the other hand, the Strontium Dog story "the Shickelgruber Grab" is a successful example, old cucumber!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're referring to DC's [Mystery In Space #114](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_in_Space_Vol_1_114) (1980), by Gerry Conway & Tom Yeates

You can read most of the panels online [here](http://slaymonstrobot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/why-time-travel-is-illegal.html)

[image: Mystery In Space1]
[image: Mystery In Space2]
[image: Mystery In Space3]
[image: Mystery In Space4]
[image: Mystery In Space5]

Comment: That's got to be it, thanks! ...Now I'm stuck wondering why there is a vacuum cleaner next to the time machine...

Comment: @Wingman4l7 - http://www.safetysign.com/images/catlog/product/large/D5941.png